# Load Kml file on google maps inside street View

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I have loaded kml file in Google map with layer satellite and hybrid and it's loaded successfully. But when i selected add street view in same location kml file path is not shown.

JavaScript Code:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.257753, 146.823688),
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
  });
}
initialize();
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer();
var kmlUrl =  'http://202.131.106.55/kml/08831R001.kml';
var kmlOptions = {
  suppressInfoWindows: true,
  preserveViewport: false,
  map: map
};
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, kmlOptions);
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="map" style="min-width: 800px; min-height: 660px"></div>
```

Can you please suggest me how can i display KML file path with google map street view. check over here  http://202.131.106.56/kmz/test.html when i click on Toggle Street View it's not showing same path in street-view.

Comment: For me work perfectly  take a look back near to the manhole road  there is the marker ...

Comment: I need roadmap path that shows in normal view, marker is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the road path is not visible butt present ..

Try using StreetViewCoverageLayer()

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewCoverageLayer

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), mapOptions);
var streetViewLayer = new google.maps.StreetViewCoverageLayer();
streetViewLayer.setMap(map);
```

Comment: I tried streetViewLayer but not shown in street-view.

Comment: I need to display markers as well depend on how many users on this road but i need to defined roadpath first through KML file.

Comment: Google Earth is showing kml path on street-view, is there any way to implement same like this with google map.

Comment: The libraries are different for what  i know ... is not possible .